# StencilJS - How to import css/sass from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I am trying to import a css file that has variables from a node_modules package.

I've attempted to copy from the stencil.config.ts, but it keeps dumping builds into the location I am trying to specify and can't find information for the next foot forward..

What I have right now is something like this:

```
  type: "www",
  dir: 'src/global',
  copy: [
    { src: '../node_modules/package/design-tokens/dist/tokens.css', dest: 'themes' }
  ]
}
```

Right now I just need to go into the node_modules and reference a css file that has variables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to import the file directly from node modules in your global css file?

In `stenil.config.ts` you have

```
// stenil.config.ts
export const config: Config = {
  globalStyle: "src/global/app.css",
  ....
}
```

In the app.css file you can import the variables from node_modules:

```
/*
 * app.css
 */

@import '~design-tokens/dist/tokens.css';

/*
 * Some other custom css here
 */
```

`~` here refers to the `node_modules` folder, so then `design_tokens` is the package that you have installed in `node_modules`.

You can also look into using sass for your app.css file instead as described here: https://stenciljs.com/docs/plugins. So you would use the `@stencil/sass` plugin shown in the link to handle the compiling, and rename your `app.css` to an `app.sass` instead. But this shouldn't be necessary if your design tokens are CSS custom properties.